# querySelector search immediate children

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, selectors-api

I have some jquery-like function:

```
function(elem) {
    return $('> someselector', elem);
};
```

The question is how can i do the same with `querySelector()`?

The problem is `>` selector in `querySelector()` requires parent to be explicitly specified. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Complete :scope polyfill

As [avetisk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/303085/avetisk) has [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18607777/489553) Selectors API 2 uses `:scope` pseudo-selector.
To make this work in all browsers (that support `querySelector`) here is the polyfill

```
(function(doc, proto) {
  try { // check if browser supports :scope natively
    doc.querySelector(':scope body');
  } catch (err) { // polyfill native methods if it doesn't
    ['querySelector', 'querySelectorAll'].forEach(function(method) {
      var nativ = proto[method];
      proto[method] = function(selectors) {
        if (/(^|,)\s*:scope/.test(selectors)) { // only if selectors contains :scope
          var id = this.id; // remember current element id
          this.id = 'ID_' + Date.now(); // assign new unique id
          selectors = selectors.replace(/((^|,)\s*):scope/g, '$1#' + this.id); // replace :scope with #ID
          var result = doc[method](selectors);
          this.id = id; // restore previous id
          return result;
        } else {
          return nativ.call(this, selectors); // use native code for other selectors
        }
      }
    });
  }
})(window.document, Element.prototype);
```

### Usage

```
node.querySelector(':scope > someselector');
node.querySelectorAll(':scope > someselector');
```

---

For historical reasons, my previous solution

Based on all answers

```
// Caution! Prototype extending
Node.prototype.find = function(selector) {
    if (/(^\s*|,\s*)>/.test(selector)) {
        if (!this.id) {
            this.id = 'ID_' + new Date().getTime();
            var removeId = true;
        }
        selector = selector.replace(/(^\s*|,\s*)>/g, '$1#' + this.id + ' >');
        var result = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        if (removeId) {
            this.id = null;
        }
        return result;
    } else {
        return this.querySelectorAll(selector);
    }
};
```

**Usage**

```
elem.find('> a');
```

Comment: `Date.now()` is not supported by older browsers, and could be replaced with `new Date().getTime()`

Answer (score 201):

Though it's not a full answer, you should keep an eye on the [W3C Selector API v.2](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/selectors-api2/) which is already available in most browser, both desktop and mobile, except IE (Edge seems to support): [see full support list](https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Ascope).

```
function(elem) {
  return elem.querySelectorAll(':scope > someselector');
};
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. 
However, [browser support is limited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope#Browser_compatibility) and you'll need a shim if you want to use it. I built [scopedQuerySelectorShim](https://github.com/lazd/scopedQuerySelectorShim) for this purpose.

Comment: The :scope attribute [has been removed from the current specification](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/552).

Comment: Actually, `:scope` is still specified at https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-scope-pseudo. So far it's only the `<style scoped>` attribute that got removed; it's unclear whether that will also lead to `:scope` being removed (since `<style scoped>` was an important use case for `:scope`).

Comment: What a surprise: only Edge doesn't support this : )

Comment: In 2021 this is now supported in all modern browsers.

Comment: Adding to @DisgruntledGoat's comment, modern browsers in this scopes means all major ones except IE, which already reached its End of Support anyways

Comment: There may be a little confusion about @tobi 's comment, to be clear `scoped` ATTRIBUTE was dropped, HOWEVER `:scope` PSEUDO-CLASS [now has crossbrowser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope#browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 36):

You can't. There's no selector that will simulate your starting point.

The way jQuery does it (more because of a way that `qsa` behaves that is not to their liking), is that they check to see if `elem` has an ID, and if not, they temporarily add an ID, then create a full selector string.

Basically you'd do:

```
var sel = '> someselector';
var hadId = true;
if( !elem.id ) {
    hadID = false;
    elem.id = 'some_unique_value';
}

sel = '#' + elem.id + sel;

var result = document.querySelectorAll( sel );

if( !hadId ) {
    elem.id = '';
}
```

This certainly isn't jQuery code, but from what I remember, it is basically what they do. Not just in this situation, but in any situation where you're running a selector from the context of a nested element.

[Source code for Sizzle](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L1170-1201)

Comment: Correct at the time of writing, but see @avetisk's answer for an updated method.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to eventually find direct children (and not e.g. `> div > span`), you can try [Element.matches()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches):

```js
const elem = document.body
const elems = [...elem.children].filter(e => e.matches('b'))

console.log(elems)
```

```html
<a>1</a>
<b>2</b>
<b>3</b>
<b>4</b>
<s>5</s>
```

Answer (score 6):

**CLAIM**

Personally I would take the answer from patrick dw, and +1 his answer, my answer is for seeking alternative solution. I don't think it deserves a downvote.

Here is my attempt :

```
function q(elem){
    var nodes = elem.querySelectorAll('someSeletor');
    console.log(nodes);
    for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
        if(nodes[i].parentNode === elem) return nodes[i];
    }
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/Lgaw5/8/

Comment: Couple of problems with that. @disfated wants it to work with `querySelector`, which means that `:eq()` can't be used. Even if it could, your selector would return the element that is `:eq()` to its appearance on the page, not `:eq()` to the index of its parent (which is where you're getting the `idx`).

Comment: +1 about the :eq() & querySelector. And I should add the context $(elem).parent().

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work either. When the selector runs from the context of the parent, it starts with the left most child and finds all matching elements no matter how deeply nested, the continues on. So say the `elem` is at index 4, but there's a previous sibling that has a different `tagName`, but it has nested inside it an element with the matching `tagName`, that nested element will be included in the results before the one you're targeting, again throwing off the index. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgaw5/1/)

Comment: ...anyway, what you're ultimately doing is a more complex version of the code in the question, which does work. `$('> someselector', elem);` ;o)

Comment: Yes but you needed to hard code that single  increment. That would require prior knowledge of it. If I add another similar element, it's broken again. ;o) http://jsfiddle.net/Lgaw5/3/

Comment: well, good, but that's just for some thoughts for alternative solution, even it is not a good one, it doesn't deserve a down vote, right?

Comment: No, I think your latest answer looks better. Still checking it out. I wasn't the one who down-voted you.

Comment: You forgot to post the link. ;o) ...ah, you must mean your updated answer. :op

Comment: Well that works, but I'm not sure how it relates to the question at this point.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying. (I was falling asleep last night.) Yes, that would seem to work. +1

Answer (score 5):

If you know the tag name of the element that you’re looking into, then you can use it in the selector to achieve what you want.

For example if you have a `<select>` that has `<option>`s and `<optgroups>`, and you only want the `<option>`s that are its immediate children, not the ones inside `<optgoups>`:

```
<select>
  <option>iPhone</option>
  <optgroup>
    <option>Nokia</option>
    <option>Blackberry</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

So, having a reference to the select element, you can — surprisingly — get its immediate children like this:

```
selectElement.querySelectorAll('select > option')
```

It seems to work in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox, but didn’t test in IEs. =/

Comment: Warning: This answer is not actually limiting scope. If pattern is repeated deeper nest level it's still will be selected even if it's not direct children.

`<ul id="start">
 <li>A</li>
 <li>
  <ul>
   <li>b</li>
   <li>c</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
var result = document.getElementById('start').querySelectorAll('ul>li');`

-> All 4 li elements will be selected!

Comment: God forbid there was two `<select>` elements in the same parent.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a simplified, generic method for running any CSS selector query over only direct children - it also accounts for combined queries, like `"foo[bar], baz.boo"`:

```
var count = 0;
function queryChildren(element, selector) {
  var id = element.id,
      guid = element.id = id || 'query_children_' + count++,
      attr = '#' + guid + ' > ',
      selector = attr + (selector + '').replace(',', ',' + attr, 'g');
  var result = element.parentNode.querySelectorAll(selector);
  if (!id) element.removeAttribute('id');
  return result;
}


*** Example Use ***

queryChildren(someElement, '.foo, .bar[xyz="123"]');
```

Answer (score 2):

There’s a [query-relative](https://github.com/dfcreative/query-relative) lib, which is quite handy replacement for *query-selector*. It polyfills children selector `'> *'` and `:scope` (inc. IE8), as well as normalizes `:root` selector.
Also it provides some special relative pseudos like `:closest`, `:parent`, `:prev`, `:next`, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

That worked for me:

```
Node.prototype.search = function(selector)
{
    if (selector.indexOf('@this') != -1)
    {
        if (!this.id)
            this.id = "ID" + new Date().getTime(); 
        while (selector.indexOf('@this') != -1)
            selector = selector.replace('@this', '#' + this.id);
        return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    } else 
        return this.querySelectorAll(selector);
};
```

you will have to pass the @this keywork before the > when you want to search for immediate children.

Comment: Seems the same as the currenty accepted [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6481641/489553)... Btw, what's the point of weird "@this" syntax? Why not just test for ">" with regexp?

Answer (score 0):

check if element have id else add random id and do search based on it

```
function(elem) {
      if(!elem.id)
          elem.id = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 10);
      return elem.querySelectorAll(elem.id + ' > someselector');
    };
```

will do same thing as

```
$("> someselector",$(elem))
```