# Get length of child element with a specific class name?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am able to get the elements with the specific class name, but unable to retrive the length of the amount of elements with that specific class name.

How should I go about getting the number of elements with the specific class name of a child element?

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4CQu/1/)**

```
document.getElementById('contact').onsubmit = function() {
    var children = this.children;

    for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i].className == 'req') {

            console.log(children[i]); //defined
            console.log(children[i].length); //undefined

        }
    }

    return false;
};
```

Comment: Use `console.log(children[i].value.length);` instead

Comment: `children[i]` is a specific DOM element. Why do you expect it to have a `.length` property?

Comment: children.getElementsByClassName('req'); ??

Comment: @theshadowmonkey: `children` is a `HTMLCollection` which has no such method.

Comment: @Shivam: Do you actually want to use the `required` attribute instead of a class name?

Comment: @Bergi That would be my preferred method of choice, but when I set `required` attribute to an element, the browser itself handles the validation, which I would want to overwrite by creating my own validation script, but not sure how too. Which is why I am using class name `req` instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090369/disable-validation-of-html5-form-elements discusses a few tricks that let you use your own logic :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simple solution to this myself:

Please let me know what you guys think?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4CQu/14/)

```
document.getElementById('contact').onsubmit = function() {
    var req = this.getElementsByClassName('req').length;
    console.log(req);
    return false;
};
```

Comment: That doesn't search only the direct children, but it will probably work well for you :-)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481612/queryselector-search-immediate-children also. You could do `document.querySelectorAll("#contact > .req").length` though

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to **count** the number of child elements with that class:

```
document.getElementById('contact').onsubmit = function() {
    var children = this.children;
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
        if (children[i].classList.contains('req'))
            count++;
    console.log(count+" of "+children.length+" have the class 'req'");
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Yes, this also works well, and was what I was looking to accomplish myself, but I figured out a more simple way to do this. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `children[i].value.length` to get values.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4CQu/6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call( children )
```

sorry this what I meant http://jsfiddle.net/e4CQu/15/

Comment: You can loop directly through the `this.children` as well.

Comment: u can loop but not get lenght

Comment: Of course the collection has a `.length` property, otherwise your `slice` conversion wouldn't work at all.

Comment: mm true, so if I can ask why his children[i].length resulted undefined?

Comment: @Bergi why did u comment "children[i] is a specific DOM element. Why do you expect it to have a .length property?" ?

Answer (score 0):

DOM elements do not have a `length` property. If you are trying to get how many characters are in it, you should instead be using the `length` property of `value`, like this: `children[i].value.length`