# How to get javascript function work only in div by class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Have a HTML / javascript :

```
<section class="on">
    <select id="comboA" onchange="getComboA(this)">
        <option value="[xfvalue_monthprice1]">100</option>
        <option value="[xfvalue_monthprice2]">200</option>
        <option value="[xfvalue_monthprice3]">300</option>
        <option value="[xfvalue_monthprice5]">400</option>
    </select>

    <div id="prdiv">
        <p id="prid"></p>
    </div>
</section>

<script>
    function getComboA(sel) {
        var value = sel.value;  
        document.getElementById("prid").innerHTML = value;
    }
</script>
```

---

Sections are more than 2. Class "on" of the section is dinamyc (on / off). How can I force the function to work only in section with "on" class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have tagged the question with jquery, You can use jquery to bind the change event only elements with a specific class name.

As the class name changes dynamically, you need to use delegation as well

```
$(document).on("change", "section.on select", function() {
    $("#prid").html($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: works only for the 1-st section. I guess it's because of the main div (before section, which also has class "on"). So, how can we get not ".on select" , but "section.on select" . Thanks in advance!

Comment: works well. but also I have to select not the "#prid" , but ".on #prid" . Now it works, thanks a lot!

Comment: Mark it as anwer, if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need a javascript solution.
Here is my try:

HTML:

```
<section class="on">
    <select id="comboA">
        <option value="100">100</option>
        <option value="200">200</option>
        <option value="300">300</option>
        <option value="400">400</option>
    </select>
</section>
<section class="off">
    <select id="comboB">
        <option value="100">100</option>
        <option value="200">200</option>
        <option value="300">300</option>
        <option value="400">400</option>
    </select>
</section>
<div id="prdiv"><p id="prid"></p> </div>
```

JS:

```
var selCombo = document.querySelector(".on select");
selCombo.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var value = this.value;  
    document.getElementById("prid").innerHTML = value;
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/szj4rL2d/2/)**

Comment: also works, but only for the 1-st section. Need ".on #prid" . See upper, solved with jquery. Thanks!

Comment: It is possible to achieve it through 'querySelector', but its [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope#Browser_compatibility) is limited. Also, [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481612/queryselector-search-immediate-children) for your reference for selecting the immediate child.

Comment: If you notice, I've separated `#prdiv` from both the sections and kept it at the end. And as per requirement, the script only runs for the section with `class="on"`