# querySelectorAll root elements without using :scope

Tags: javascript, children, selectors-api

Let's assume we have this HTML structure:

```
<div id='test-div'>
    <div class='random-class-1'>
        <div class='useless-element-1'>
        </div>
        <div class='useless-element-2'>
        </div>
        <p>Just a paragraph, and useless</p>
    </div>
    <div class='random-class-2'>
        <div class='useless-element-3'>
        </div>
        <div class='useless-element-4'>
        </div>
        <div class='useless-element-5'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to select all children "DIV elements" (not grandchildren) inside the first DIV (in this example with id='test-div'), not from document but from element (div) itself.

So, I don't want to use the "query" below because I already have selected the element DIV [object HTMLDivElement]:

```
// I don't want to use this query
var children = document.querySelectorAll("div > div");
```

Just an example to achieve this (https://jsfiddle.net/t4gxt65k/):

```
// I already have selected DIV element 
var el = document.getElementById("test-div")
// OR var el = document.querySelectorAll("#test-div");

var children = el.querySelectorAll(":scope > div");
```

But because of browser incompatibility I don't want to use ":scope"

The real question is:

How can I get the children (only DIV elements) of [object HTMLDivElement] using pure JavaScript?

Comment: Please comment me if the question is not understandable :)

Comment: Could you not then again go in and do: `var children = document.querySelectorAll("#test-div > div")`

Comment: This is OK for this example but in real application the DIV doesn't have an ID and I have only [object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: Consider this: you have only the result from document.getElementById("test-div")

Comment: Thats a good point. I just found out you can actually access you own direct element so what you could do is for example in the case of a select `var options = select.querySelectorAll("select > option");`. But in the case of multiple divs I'm not totally sure

Comment: That's my problem. It works with :scope as shown on example but don't like it.

Comment: There's a [polyfill](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17989803/367865) for `:scope` in conjunction with `.querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: Yeah, Marat also posted a similar example. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get direct children of an element use a combination of [**parentNode.children**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) or [**parentNode.childNodes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes), and [**Array.prototype.reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this:

```
var children = Array.prototype.reduce.call(el.children, function(acc, e) {
    if(e.tagName == "DIV")
        acc.push(e);
    return acc;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 5):

As an option, you could set a temporary *unique attribute* for your scope element, and then use `querySelectorAll()` for its parent with the attribute selector prepended to what you would place after the `:scope` selector:

```
// The `scope` variable stores a reference to the scope element.
var attrName = '_scope'  + Date.now();
scope.setAttribute(attrName, '');
var children = scope.parentNode.querySelector('[' + attrName + '] > DIV');
```

I’m not sure about how fast it is though.

Fwiw, specifically for getting *child* elements, there is the [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) DOM property:

```
var children = scope.children;
```

Comment: Nice idea, basically adding a temporary attribute to use as reference. Love it!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [@Ibrahims answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125395/queryselectorall-root-elements-without-using-scope#answer-42125487) in selecting children but less complicated since it does not address prototype and reduce. Instead it uses [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Element.matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches). Element.matches makes it more versatile since it uses a normal selector string (as you would in `querySelectorAll`).

```
Array.from(rootElement.children)
  .filter(elm => elm.matches('div'))
```

```js
const rootElement = document.getElementById('test-div')

Array.from(rootElement.children)
  .filter(elm=>elm.matches('div'))
  .forEach(elm=>elm.classList.add('matched'))
```

```css
div {
  padding: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px gray inset;
}
.matched {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red inset;
}
```

```html
<div id='test-div'>
    <div class='random-class-1'>
        <div class='useless-element-1'></div>
        <div class='useless-element-2'></div>
        <p>Just a paragraph, and useless</p>
    </div>
    <div class='random-class-2'>
        <div class='useless-element-3'></div>
        <div class='useless-element-4'></div>
        <div class='useless-element-5'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```