# How to filter elements in vanilla Javascript like in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, in jQuery, if i want all `<div>` and `<p>` elements, I do this:

```
var $x = $("p, div");
```

And then if i want all the `<div>` elements in x, then I do this:

```
var $divs = $x.filter("div");
```

So how do i do this simple `filter` thing in vanilla JavaScript?

For example, to select all `<div>` and `<p>`, then I can do this:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("div, p");
```

But vanilla JavaScript doesn't have the filter function like in jQuery, so I can't do this:

```
var divs = x.filter("div"); // ERROR
```

Hope someone can help me with this :-)

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Some comments/answers have suggested to do something like **.tagName == "DIV"** to find the divs, however, i want a solution with a string selector like in jQuery.

The reason is because i also want to filter with attributes, classes and even multiple selectors where you put in comma. And the string selector must be dynamic.

That means, i dont know whats in the selector. It could be "div[foo='asd'], .bar" or "#hello, [xx='yy'], p"

So  i cant just hardcode the .tagName == "DIV", beacuse i dont know whats in the selector string.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I think you can just do `[anyDomElement].GetElementsByTagName("div")`

Comment: Have you opened the jQuery core code and taken a look at the `.filter()` method?

Comment: Why not just write a wrapper that looks like the first code snippet but actually does the second?

Comment: there is no such thing as "native" JavaScript ...it is commonly referred to as "vanilla" or ECMA6 script.

Comment: @MartinZeitler welcome to the [javascript] tag. What is `ECMA6 script`?

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan see ...
http://es6-features.org

Comment: @MartinZeitler so you mean [**ECMAScript**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) ;)

Comment: maybe this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481612/queryselector-search-immediate-children/18607777

Comment: something alike `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll( selector ));` - while one can also filter nodes by xPath: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) function to check if a CSS selector matches a given element.

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("div, p");
var divs = [];

// Iterate through the elements that the first query selector matched
//  (is a paragraph or a div tag)
for (var elem of x) {
    // Check if the given element matches the second query selector
    //  (is a div tag)
    if (elem.matches('div')) {
        divs.push(elem);
    }
}
```

This code can be written more succinctly (and with more modern code) using:

```
let x = document.querySelectorAll("div, p");
let divs = Array.from(x).filter(elem => elem.matches("div"));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const elems = document.querySelectorAll('p, div');
const divs = [...elems].filter(e => {
  return e.tagName == 'DIV'
});

console.log(divs)
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<p id="p1"></p>
<p id="p2"></p>
<p id="p3"></p>
```

you can change `e.tagName` to filter with something else :

```js
const elems = document.querySelectorAll('p, div');

const divs = [...elems].filter(e => {
  return e.tagName == 'DIV'
});

const byId = [...elems].filter(e => {
  return e.id == 'div1'
});

const byClass = [...elems].filter(e => {
  return e.className == 'class1'
});

console.log(byClass)
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="class1"></div>
<div id="div2" class="class1"></div>
<div id="div3" class="class2"></div>
<p id="p1" class="class1"></p>
<p id="p2" class="class2"></p>
<p id="p3" class="class2"></p>
```

Comment: how do you filter by ID or class? Or by Attribute selector `[]`?

Comment: just replace `e.tagName` with `e.className` or `e.id` , like : `const byClass = [...elems].filter(e => {return e.className == 'class1'});`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan , def. hardcoding and replacing is not advisable, but this just gives an idea, ideally, this would be tweaked and wrapped in a function with arguments for better use.

Answer (score 1):

you can combine [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [Element.matches()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("div, p");
var divs = x.filter(y => y.matches("div"));

// for p tags
var paragraphs = x.filter(y => y.matches("p"));

//for both div and p tags
var mix = x.filter(y => y.matches("div, p"));
```

Comment: `Element.matches()` works really well. The only thing wrong with this answer is that `.filter()` isn't a method of a NodeList, so you have to convert the NodeList to an Array first. Example: `[...x].filter()`

Answer (score 0):

querySelectorAll returns a NodeList not an array.

You'll need to convert it to an array

```
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(x);
var divs = arr.filter(el => { return el.tagName == 'DIV' });
```

Comment: how does this answers the *"how to replicate jQuery's `.filter()`"*

Comment: Sorry, for assuming knowledge here. I updated my answer to be more complete.

I figured converting the NodeList to Array would allow the user to understand .filter is now available.

Anywho, now with the .filter() function you can sort by tag name.

Comment: `Array.prototype` can be used in place of `[]` to avoid the unnecessary array instantiation.

Comment: what about `const arr = [...document.querySelectorAll("selector")].filter(` etc

Comment: Also, if you like shorthands, `y` is quite odd. `el` on the other hand is well known...

Answer (score 0):

A very naive approach:

```
function get(selector) {
 const els = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

 return {
   selector,
   length: els.length,
   get: i => els[i],
   [Symbol.iterator]: () => els[Symbol.iterator](),
   filter: f => get(selector + ", " + f)
  };
}
```

Usable as:

```
const menus = get(".menu");
for(const el of menus) console.log(el);
console.log(menus.filter("div").get(0));
```

Comment: Sorry what should `menus.filter("div").get(0)` give back?

Comment: @roko the first `.menu` that is a `div`