# Extending element methods in JSDOM

Tags: node.js, jsdom

How can we to extend element methods in JSDOM to all opened pages?

```js
// load the module and few pages
const JSDOM = require("jsdom").JSDOM;
var dom1 = new JSDOM("<p>1st</p><p>2nd</p>");
var dom2 = new JSDOM("<p>1st</p><p>2nd</p>");
...

// add methods such as: map, filter, searchText...
var window = dom1.window;
window.NodeList.prototype.map = 
    function (cb) { return Array.from(this).map(cb) };
...

// Execution:
dom1.window.document.querySelectorAll('p').map(p=> p.textContent);
// returns: [ '1st', '2nd' ]
dom2.window.document.querySelectorAll('p').map(p=> p.textContent);
// throws an error
```

Is it possible to extend NodeList **ones**, without loading it for **every new document**?
Something more like:

```
JSDOM.installedInterfaces.NodeList.prototype.map = ...
```

Comment: did you ever work this out? I'd like to add a querySelectorAll polyfill described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17989803/1243605 but need access to JSDOM's Element prototype.