# Child selector using `querySelectorAll` on a DOM collection

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, selectors-api

Let's presume you got a list with nested child lists.

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

And use `document.querySelectorAll()` to make a selection:

```
var ul = document.querySelectorAll("ul");
```

How can i use the `ul` collection to get the direct child elements?

```
ul.querySelectorAll("> li"); 
// Gives 'Error: An invalid or illegal string was specified'
```

Let's presume `ul` is cached somehow (otherwise i could have done `ul > li` directly).

In jQuery this works:

```
$("ul").find("> li");
```

But it doesn't in native `querySelectorAll`. Any solutions?

Comment: That selector doesn't really make sense. With jQuery you'd use `.children("li")` instead of `.find("> li")`. I'm surprised that works at all, actually.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL `.find('> li ul span')` is useful, but not so much on its own like in the OP's example.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL the example is a bit contrived, but it definitely has a real-world use case :)

Answer (score 41):

The correct way to write a selector that is "rooted" to the current element is to use [`:scope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope).

```
ul.querySelectorAll(":scope > li");
```

See my answer here for an explanation and a robust, cross-browser solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21126966/1170723

Comment: Good to see this exists! :)

Comment: Keep in mind the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ascope#Browser_compatibility): Chrome: yes, FF: 32, IE: no, opera: no, Safari: 7

Comment: in addition to what @Web_Designer said, to this day it is *still* also not supported in Microsoft Edge. Trying to use 'scope' in querySelectorAll gives a syntax error. So much for the "you don't need jQuery" camp.

Answer (score 13):

Because the `ul` returned is a NodeList, it doesn't implicitly loop over its contents like a jQuery collection. You'd need to use `ul[0].querySelectorAll()` or better still select the `ul` with `querySelector()`.

Besides that, `querySelectorAll()` won't take a `>` and work from its current context. However, you can get it to work using [lazd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22029375/31671) (though check the browser compatibility), or any of these workarounds (which should have no browser issues)...

```
[].filter.call(ul.querySelectorAll("li"), function(element){
     return element.parentNode == ul;
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLpCy/).

This will select all `li` elements that are descendants of your `ul`, and then remove the ones which are not direct descendants.

Alternatively, you could get all `childNodes` and then filter them...

```
[].filter.call(ul.childNodes, function(node) {
    return node.nodeType == 1 && node.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'li';
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kH53j/).

Comment: Yup, that seems like a workable solution. Too bad it takes three lines of code what could be done in a single character :)

Note that `filter()` won't work because `ul` is a NodeList, so you need to do `Array.prototype.slice.call` first.

Comment: @Husky You can always add it to `Element.prototype` as a function :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over the `NodeList` returned by `document.querySelectorAll()` and then call `element.querySelectorAll()` for each element in that list.