# select child element using parent class

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery we put select child element using like this

```
$('.parentClass .childClass')....
```

is there any way to select child class using parent class in javascript

Comment: Can you give us an example?

Comment: You could use `$('.parent').children()`

Comment: Question is unclear.

Comment: I think this is already answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10189936/140638

Answer (score 2):

For Javascript try this

```
document.querySelectorAll('.parentClass .childClass')
```

You can use css selector as argument in this function.
This function not supported in lower version of IE

Comment: it does have good support, IE8+, with one exception fo IE8 it should be CSS2 selectors only

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<ul class="example">
  <li class="child">Coffee</li>
  <li class="child">Tea</li>
</ul>
```

javascript:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("example")[0];
list.getElementsByClassName("child")[0].innerHTML = "Milk";
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear but if you want to get all nested child elements which has class, this can be work:

$("parentElementSelector").find("[class]")

But if you want to just next child elements you can use this:

$("parentElementSelector").children("[class]")