# Get Element From CSS Full Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having the following CSS Full selector "body > div > p"
I need to fetch the element using the above css selector using javascript/jquery. Is there any built in function available to achive this ?

Comment: `$("body > div > p")`?

Comment: In plain JS you can use `document.querySelector('body > div > p')` or `document.querySelectorAll('body > div > p')`

Comment: Seems like the kind of question that does not indicate any research effort

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Child selector using \`querySelectorAll\` on a DOM collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189903/child-selector-using-queryselectorall-on-a-dom-collection)

Comment: There is a mistake in my actual css slector, now the issue is resolved. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single selection:

```
document.querySelector('body > div > p')
```

Multi selection (as array):

```
document.querySelectorAll('body > div > p')
```

These were pure JS.

If you want to use jQuery

```
$('body > div > p')
```