# When using querySelectorAll, is there a way to reference the immediate children of the context node, without using IDs?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, selectors-api

Say I have an HTML structure like

```
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">
    <div id="c"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To do a query for the children of "a" using querySelectorAll I can do something like

```
//Get "b", but not "c"
document.querySelectorAll('#a > div')
```

**My question is**: is it possible to do this without the ID, referencing the node directly? I tried doing

```
var a_div = document.getElementById('a')
a_div.querySelectorAll('> div') //<-- error here
```

but I get an error telling me that the selector I used is invalid.

---

And in case anyone is wondering, my real use case would be something more complicated like '> .foo .bar .baz' so I would prefer to avoid manual DOM traversal. Currently I am adding a temporary id to the root div but that seems like an ugly hack...

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680876/use-queryselectorall-to-retrieve-direct-children

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't a way <sup>(yet)</sup> to reference all childs of some element without using a reference to that element. Because `>` is a [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-selectors4-20110929/#child-combinators), which represents a relationship between a parent and child element, a [simple selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-selectors4-20110929/#simple) (a parent) is necessary (which is missing in you example).

In a comment, [BoltClock said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440725/when-using-queryselectorall-is-there-a-way-to-reference-the-immediate-children/11440779#comment15104621_11440779) that the [Selectors API Level 2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api2) defines a method [`findAll`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api2/#the-apis)<sup>name *may* change</sup> *"which accepts as an argument what will probably be known as a relative selector (a selector that can start with a combinator rather than a compound selector)"*.
When this is implemented, it can be used as follows:

```
a_div.findAll('> div');
```

Comment: What is the usual workaround for this though? Is adding a (temporary) id to the root element the only way?

Comment: @missingno Yes. The other method is to loop through all `.childNodes`, and test whether the child is a div using `childNodes[i].nodeName.toUpperCase()=='div'`.

Comment: More technically, "Because `>` is a *combinator*", you cannot do this with `querySelectorAll()`. In the near future, you'll be able to do this with `findAll()`, which accepts as an argument what will probably be known as a relative selector (a selector that can start with a combinator rather than a compound selector). See the [Selectors API level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api2) spec.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for the info, I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 11):

```
document.querySelector('#a').querySelectorAll(':scope > div')
```

I am not sure about browser support, but I use it on chrome and chrome mobile packaged apps and it works fine.

Comment: [MDN on `:scope` in `querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope#Browser_compatibility): Chrome, Firefox 32+, Safari 7, not Opera, not IE.

Answer (score 0):

I think I must be misunderstanding your question, but this is how I'm interpreting it..

```
var a = document.getElementById('a')
var results = a.querySelectorAll('div');
```

results will hold all your child divs now.

Comment: `results` will not only hold the child divs, but **all** descendant divs.

Comment: I want to exclude the "c" div from the results though. The '#a > div' selector only returns the "b" div.