# Parent > Child selector in querySelector

Tags: javascript, selector

How do I get [> p > a](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) working in querySelector ?

```
<div id="container">
    <p>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
    </p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">    
console.log(document.getElementById("container").querySelector("> p > a"));
</script>
```

> SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified

Comment: You want to translate jQuery code to pure JS? Is that it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When using querySelectorAll, is there a way to reference the immediate children of the context node, without using IDs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440725/when-using-queryselectorall-is-there-a-way-to-reference-the-immediate-children)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the leading `>` that's stopping you. If you're going to use `querySelector` you might as well get the container by that means, too, rather than using `getElementById`.

```
document.querySelector("#container > p > a")
```

Comment: That's just an example, I guess. The question is stated at the first line: "How do I get `> p > a` working in querySelector?".

Comment: Well if the query is literally that, it won't work, as you can't lead with `>`, and query selector syntax has no reference to self (it would be good if you could do something like `'_self > p > a'`. I guess you'd have to fall back to `childNodes`?

Comment: Or just wait for `findAll` to be implemented. See the linked [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440725/when-using-queryselectorall-is-there-a-way-to-reference-the-immediate-children).

Comment: [Deprecated these days](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Chrome/API/Browser_API/findAll).