# querySelector direct child only of referenced element

Tags: javascript

For example,

```
var relevantItems = ul.querySelectorAll('li.someClass[data-x=someData]')
```

Should only match these elements from the outer, referenced `<ul>`:

```
<ul>
  <!-- This <li> matches -->
  <li class="someClass" data-x="someData">
    <ul>
      <!-- depending on the query, there may be some extra matches within the hierarchy, but these should not be searched or included in the results -->
    </ul>
  </li>
  <!-- need to also includes additional matches like this one: -->
  <li class="someClass" data-x="someData">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Right now I have a couple of options:

1. Use JavaScript to loop over `childNodes`/`children` array and compare the `className` and `dataset.x` variables traditionally.
2. Give each `<ul>` its own `id` and use the `#id>` prefix feature like so:

   ```
   ul.querySelectorAll('#' + ul.id + ' > li....')
   ```

Is there a simpler syntax, or alternative function, e.g. filtering the `childNodes` List somehow, to achieve the same query? (without adding an external library i.e. jQuery)

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a "good" way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680876/using-queryselectorall-to-retrieve-direct-children

Comment: Thanks! That thread has the answer I was looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21126966/463304