# How can I get a Node's only direct children with a specific class name?

Tags: javascript

How can I get a Node's only direct children with a specific class name?

Example

```
<div class="list-group">
  <div class="list-group-item">
    <div class="list-group"> <!--I have this-->
      <div class="list-group-item"> <!--And I want to reach this-->
        <div class="list-group">
          <div class="list-group-item"></div> <!--Not this-->
          <div class="list-group-item"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="list-group-item"></div> <!--And get this-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a list-group that contains items and groups and I want to keep that hierarchy and get a list-group's only direct list-group-items.

How can I do so?

Comment: Add Your current selector.

Comment: this question may have been answered in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3680876/5409815) using the `:scope` pseudo class. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope#direct_children) for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't mentioned if you use any JS frameworks, but with JQuery it is fairly simple... just use `children()`

In example `$("#haveThis").children()`

You can also filter children like: `$("#haveThis").children("list-group-item")`

docs: https://api.jquery.com/children/

For vanilla JS I'd do this:

```
[].slice.call(document.getElementById("havethis").children).filter(el=>el.className==='list-group-item')
```

Comment: Edit : I know about the JQuery solution but I didn't know I could use JQuery functions on var Node like $(Node).children

Comment: If you don't target IE or Opera Mini, it's pretty safe to use `Array.from` instead of `[].slice.call`.

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JS (if you're not using jQuery) `element.children` (where element is the parent you wish to query) will return a list of all direct child nodes, you would then itterate over the list list, looking for `node.className = "list-group-item";`
I've not found a way to do this with standard CSS selectors, so a coded solution seems to be the only option.

Answer (score -4):

Get all elements with the specified class name:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("list-group-item");
```

Link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: This will get all elements in the doc with that class, and as such does not answer the question.

Comment: Yes, it's true but you can filter it out. Just put x[0]

Comment: But x[0] will just get the first element, irrelvant of its position in the DOM.