# How to tell Javascript getElementByClassName to get all the element of a ul, instead of repeating the class name in each li?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to clean my html/css. How can I get this Javascript to still work, without inserting the class name in each li element from the ul?
How to make the html more pretty and readable?

```js
const ProfileForm = document.getElementsByClassName('profile_container');
const dash = document.getElementsByClassName('dashboard_buttons');
var index;
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < dash.length; i++) {

  array.push(dash[i]);

  dash[i].onclick = function() {
    index = array.indexOf(this);

    ProfileForm[index].style.display = "block";

    var check = ProfileForm[index];

    for (var i = 0; i < ProfileForm.length; i++) {
      if (ProfileForm[i].style.display == "block" && ProfileForm[i] != check) {
        ProfileForm[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="dashboard_buttons"><i class="far fa-user"></i>Profile</li>
  <li class="dashboard_buttons"><i class="far fa-list-alt"></i>My Properties</li>
  <li class="dashboard_buttons"><i class="far fa-money-bill-alt"></i>My Offers</li>
  <li class="dashboard_buttons"><i class="fas fa-file-contract"></i>My Utilities & Ejari</li>
  <li class="dashboard_buttons"><i class="far fa-heart"></i>Favourite Properties</li>
  <li class="dashboard_buttons"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i>Messages</li>
  <li class="dashboard_buttons"><i class="fas fa-cogs"></i>Settings</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll("ul li")` I believe? [Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using querySelectorAll to retrieve direct children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680876/using-queryselectorall-to-retrieve-direct-children)

Comment: Add the class `dashboard_buttons` to the `ul` element instead of `li` elements, then you can select the wanted `li` elements using `document.querySelectorAll('.dashboard_buttons li')`. Use the same selector in the stylesheet to style the list items.

Comment: @JeremyThille, this works, please post it as answer so that I may assign it.

Comment: Nice, did so, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `document.querySelectorAll("ul li")` should work. Be careful however, as this will select *all* the `<li>` in your whole document. If you want to select a specific `<ul>`, give it a class or an ID, and select only this one :

```
<ul id="myList"><li>...<li></ul>

document.querySelectorAll("ul#myList li")
```

Comment: *as this will select all the <li> in your whole document* No. It won't select `<ol><li>`, unless that `<ol>` has a `<ul>`ancestor.

Comment: `ul#myList` can be `#myList` in your selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to notice all events within some "ancestor" element.
(Using [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/eventlistener) instead of inline event handlers allows this and also promotes separation of concerns between HTML and JavaScript.)

Since I wasn't sure what you wanted to do in your loop, the demo below just "un-highlights" all the list items (and then highlights whichever one was clicked). See the in-code comments for further explanation.

Does this show you how to accomplish what you're trying to do?

```js
// Identifies the `ul` element, and calls `hightlightItem` when user clicks inside it
const list = document.getElementsByClassName("list")[0];
list.addEventListener("click", highlightItem);

// Defines the listener function
function highlightItem(event){ //Listener can access the triggering event

  const clickedThing = event.target; // Event's `target` property is useful

  // Makes sure the click was on an `li` element before proceeding
  if(clickedThing.tagName.toLowerCase() == "li"){

    // Collects the list items
    const items = list.querySelectorAll("li");

    // Loops through the collection
    for(let item of items){

      // Changes the classList for the current item in the loop
      item.classList.remove("highlight");

      // Maybe changes it again before continuing to next item in loop
      if(item == event.target){ item.classList.add("highlight"); }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.highlight{ background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>Profile</li>
  <li>My Properties</li>
  <li>My Offers</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `document.getElementByClassName`, use `document.querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by query selector

// Get all 'li' elements in the document with class="example"

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("li.example");
```