# I want to get the InnerHTML elements from multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

I can get the InnerHTML value from a single class and output to console fine using the below

```
var price = document.getElementsByClassName("price1")[0].innerHTML;
console.log(price);
```

However, I now want to get the numeric values from 3 classes and combine them to form a single numeric value.

The HTML looks like this

```
<div class="price">
 <span class="pounds">45</span>
 <span class="seperator">.</span>
 <span class="pence">99</span>
</div>
```

The required result is to output 45.99 to the console as a numeric value.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680876/using-queryselectorall-to-retrieve-direct-children)

Comment: You could just do `+document.querySelector(".price").innerText.trim().replaceAll(" ", "")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save all values and console log the interpolation of them.
The `+` is there to transform the string into a number.

Edited for the case where two `span` elements are nested:

```js
const pounds = document.getElementsByClassName("pounds")[0].innerHTML;
const separator = document.getElementsByClassName("separator")[0].innerHTML.split('<')[0];
const pence = document.getElementsByClassName("pence")[0].innerHTML;

const price = +`${pounds}${separator}${pence}`
console.log(typeof price, price);
```

```html
<div class="price">
  <span class="pounds">45</span>
  <span class="separator">.<span class="pence">99</span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked great, but the HTML was a little wrong, in that the seperator class is nested in the pence class as below

'<span class="price">
  <span class="pounds">42</span>
  <span class="pence">
    <span class="seperator">.</span>50
  </span>
</span>'

So I get 45.<span class="range-revamp-price__separator">.</span>50

Comment: how can i remove the html code from the innerHTML of the .pence class

Comment: i do not have control of the markup unfortunately - its frustrating that its nested

Comment: In essence the innerHTML value of .pence is    <span class="seperator">.</span>50    I could do with a way of not returning the markup in the innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

here is a small approach to that.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  const prices = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
  Array.from(prices).forEach(function(oPrice){
      let currentPrice = oPrice.querySelector(".pounds").innerHTML;
      currentPrice += oPrice.querySelector(".seperator").innerHTML;
      currentPrice += oPrice.querySelector(".pence").innerHTML;
      console.log(currentPrice);
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Prices</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="price">
   <span class="pounds">45</span>
   <span class="seperator">.</span>
   <span class="pence">99</span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

All prices are selected and then the price is "assembled" using forEach via the querySelectors. Note that the "currentPrice" is a string. If you need the value as a number, the string would have to be converted. Does this help you?